# Appending formula text to specific cell on pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyodbc

I have a python app which runs 4 queries and writes results to excel file. Everything works fine but i can't find a way to append formula text into specific cell with sheetname. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query(script2, cnxn)
df3 = pd.read_sql_query(script3, cnxn)
df4 = pd.read_sql_query(script4, cnxn)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.xlsx'.format(var1, var2, var3, var4))

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name3')
df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='name4')

writer.save()
```

I want to add a formula in sheet name 4 on F2 cell so it can sumproduct the way i want on the results. I mean it should not overwrite the sheet name 4.

Thank you

Comment: Does it need to be a formula? I bet it'd be way easier to just compute that quantity and write a static value.

Comment: what do you mean, could you give me an example? here is my formula =sumproduct(c2:c999;d2:d999)/sum(d2:d999)

Comment: Just compute that quality yourself from your data frame and write it to the excel file.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner with this. Could you explain what do you mean or you meant i should write formula with opening excel file manually?

Comment: hard to give you any concrete advice without data. in general, `(df['A'] * df['B']).sum()` is the same thing as excel's `sumproduct` function applied to columns "A" and "B"

Comment: the formula is working on print but how can i append result to an existing sheet name ? .to_excel command not working with it. I tried df5 = (df4['columnName1'] * df4['columnName2']).sum() / df4['columnName2'].sum()

Comment: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html